# Specify color for splitter pane

Tags: c#, devexpress

i want to specify color for a pane splitter and this is the color i want:**#7FC6C8**
I try that it work but `how can specify for this color` and this the code:

```
 @Html.DevExpress().Splitter(
        settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "body";
            settings.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
            settings.FullscreenMode = true;
            settings.ShowCollapseBackwardButton = true;
            settings.SeparatorVisible = false;

            settings.Panes.Add(pane =>
            {
                pane.Name = "FirstSplitter";
                pane.Size = Unit.Pixel(85);


                ****pane.PaneStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;****

                pane.Panes.Add(contentPane =>
                {
                    contentPane.PaneStyle.BorderTop.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(0);
                    contentPane.PaneStyle.BorderBottom.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(0);
                    contentPane.PaneStyle.BorderRight.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(0);
                    contentPane.PaneStyle.BorderLeft.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(0);

                    contentPane.Size = Unit.Percentage(8);
```

**that's work but how can i specify a color #7FC6C8**: and this work but how specify the color **pane.PaneStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;**and thank you

Answer (score 1):

Define the custom color in code and then use in when setting the BackColor.  So for #7FC6C8 that is 127,198,200.  7F = 127, C6 = 198 and C8 = 200:

```
Color CustomColor = Color.FromArgb(127, 198, 200);
pane.PaneStyle.BackColor = CustomColor;
```